# Java: I am unable to print to a text file in a while loop, despite being able to do so before the while loop

Tags: java

I need to print out a bunch of strings to a file, but I seem to be making some mistake. There is no error message and if I put normal print statements inside the while loop; it prints those. It just does not print it to the file. A different part of the program reads another file, and gives a line to this program to write into a file.

Code:

```
public static void writeToFile (String a, String username) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner (a);
    String name = lineScan.next();

    PrintStream newFile = new PrintStream (new File (username+".txt"));  
    //The below newFile command works
    newFile.println(username);        
    if ((username.toUpperCase()).equals(name.toUpperCase()))
    {       
        int count = 0;

        while (lineScan.hasNextInt())
        {       
                int pop = lineScan.nextInt();
                String s1 = 1920 + (10*count) + ": " + pop;
                newFile.println(s1);

                count++;
        }
        newFile.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `a`? Is there any more data in it? Also you should put the close() outside the while loop. A stream should be always closed.

Comment: A is just a string. It has 1 name, and then a bunch of numbers. Thanks for the tip on close() though, didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void writeToFile (String a, String username) throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner lineScan = new Scanner (a);
String name = lineScan.next();

PrintStream newFile = new PrintStream (new File (username+".txt"));  
//The below newFile command works
newFile.println(username);        
if ((username.toUpperCase()).equals(name.toUpperCase()))
{       
    int count = 0;
    System.setOut(newFile);
    while (lineScan.hasNextLine())
    {       
            String pop = lineScan.nextLine();
            String s1 = 1920 + (10*count) + ": " + pop;
            System.out.println(s1);

            count++;
    }
    newFile.close();

}
}
```

Comment: I get this error with what you said:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 154 196 244 331 445 627 962 0 0"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at BabyNames.writeToFile(BabyNames.java:80)
 at BabyNames.main(BabyNames.java:35)

Comment: There is no error now, but nothing writes to the file except the very first newFile.println statement

Answer (score 0):

I could not see `flush()/close()` being called anywhere (Outside the if block).

flush()/close() needs to be called on the PrintStream object to actually perform write to the underlying output Stream(File, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are reading the text of the file name, not the file itself, to use the Scanner class to read a file you can use  a file object like you did so in the PrintStream.

**Fixed Code:**

```
    public static void writeToFile (String a, String username) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner (new File(a));
    String name = lineScan.next();

    PrintStream newFile = new PrintStream (new File (username+".txt"));
    //The below newFile command works
    newFile.println(username);
    if ((username.toUpperCase()).equals(name.toUpperCase()))
    {
        int count = 0;

        while (lineScan.hasNextInt())
        {
            int pop = lineScan.nextInt();
            String s1 = 1920 + (10*count) + ": " + pop;
            newFile.println(s1);

            count++;
        }


    }
     newFile.close();
     lineScan.close();
}
```